# could not find cucumber plugin for protractor test

Tags: protractor, cucumber

i am brand new to protractor and did setup as per the instructions from the protractor website. When i try to run the protractor test with the a cucumber framework i always get "Error: Error: Cannot find module 'cucumber'". Any help on this? below are by configurations.

cucumber-conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
      browserName:'chrome'
  },
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  specs: [
    './cucumber/*.feature'
  ],
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['./cucumber/*.js'],
    tags: [],                      
    strict: true,                  
    format: ["pretty"],            
    dryRun: false,                 
    compiler: []                   
  },
  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
  }
};
```

when i run `protractor cucumber-conf.js` i get below error.

```
/opt/protractor_tests
➔ protractor cucumber-conf.js
(node:5681) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[12:06:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:06:55] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[12:06:57] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'cucumber'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.module.exports.load (/opt/protractor_tests/node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework/lib/cucumberLoader.js:5:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/protractor_tests/node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework/index.js:5:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
[12:06:57] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: Have you installed cucumber module?. If not add it to your package.json `npm install -g cucumber -S`

Comment: i tried. still facing the same error. any more help please.

Comment: Follow the steps in this blog. https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-protractor-and-cucumber

Comment: Add your package.json in the question